# App closes when i try to execute "OkHttpClient.execute()"

Tags: java, api, android-studio

Here is my Code:

```
public boolean GetJwtToken(UserModel user){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(ApiUrl + "api/DoAccess/" + user.Username + "/" + user.Username)
            .build();

    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i try to execute this Line

```
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

My App closes.
When i Try do Debug, i automatically Jump into this class:

[image]

I dont find any Thrown Exception.

Hope you guys can Help my :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your question, that the code does not enter the catch block you have in the code?

Comment: Sry for that misssing information. My question is, what i have to do that the code is running without Excreption :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching an IOException (Checked Exception), but the code is throwing a RuntimeException (unchecked Exception), that's whyh it's not entering into your catch block.

If you want to catch, you need to catch RuntimeException also, but I will investigate on the error, since if the code fails and runs a RuntimeException, there should be another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can see the actual exception by changing catch (IOException e)  to catch (Exception e)
Possibly the underlying cause is you make network call on main UI thread, use AsynTask if that is the case.